# How can I create a carousel with multiple rows?

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am searching for a carousel that has multiple rows. For example 3 rows - 9 items. A jQuery carousel would be nice, but I only can find carousels with 1 row.

I want this setup. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this problem, and wanted to use [Slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) because it has tons of other capabilities. It sets each image (set inside a div) as a "slide", and you can choose how many slides you want to display at a time.

To make multiple rows with Slick.js, you nest the divs containing the images into another div, which slick sees as one slide. Then, you float the child divs to create the grid of images. There's a lot of ways to do this - I also used line breaks with "clear: both" CSS set to break the images into a new row.

Here's the relevant code for a 2x2 grid:

HTML

```
<div class="slider">

    <!-- This will be considered one slide -->
    <div>    
        <div class="grandchild">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div class="grandchild">
            <img src="" />
        </div>

        <br class="clearboth">

        <div class="grandchild">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div class="grandchild">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The second slide -->
    <div>
        <div class="grandchild">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grandchild {
    float: left;
}
.clearboth {
    clear: both;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Great answer, but there is a fundamental issue with this type of solution when dealing with responsive websites. One awesome benefit of Slick.js is that it will handle responsive design with a small amount of JS init code. However, if you create a grid containing sorted elements for a specific size, it will not work properly for various browser widths.

Comment: True. You could use breakpoints to change the slides to show/scroll and having nested divs that stack vertically, but you'd be stuck at a fixed height (so if you had a grid fixed at 4 images high, you could break from 4x4 to 3x4, 2x4, etc). Is there a better solution out there for responsive design?

Comment: Hi KamHarrah and @Kevin Zych do either of you have a solution to centering these thumbnails in side the slick slide? I'm running into this problem now.

Comment: Sorry @gwar9, nothing off hand

Answer (score 5):

Slick has a parameter called rows, this might help you, e.g.:

```
$('.b-grid-item').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 5,
    rows: 3
});
```

This produces a grid with 5 columns and 3 rows. Only obstacle with this. Items flow from top to bottom, so in your first row you would have the order: 1, 4, 7,...

Answer (score 1):

Each of you slider items has to be its own grid to do so.

For example:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
        <ul class="grid">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            …
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <ul class="grid">
            …
</div>
```