# Grouped slides in slick slider

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Is it possible to "group" slides on a custom pagination with slick slider. So slide one can have 3 slides inside which is navigatable on the slider nav.

I think I might have to create a synched slider for it, but not sure how this would all stick together.

You can see better what I mean here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsxgG.jpg

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800622/slick-carousel-in-two-rows-left-to-right