# Swiper: Can I sort elements per row and grouped?

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I currently have this code

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    spaceBetween: 32,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,
    slidesPerGroup: 2
});
```

Which sorts my Slides like this

```
|-----|-----|
|01 03|05 07|
|02 04|06 08|
|-----|-----|
```

Now my question is if it is possible to sort the slides from left to right as a group, like this

```
|-----|-----|
|01 02|05 06|
|03 04|07 08|
|-----|-----|
```

`slidesPerColumnFill: 'row'` does not work since it would "destroy" the actual group:

```
|-----|-----|
|01 02|03 04|
|05 06|07 08|
|-----|-----|
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800622/slick-carousel-in-two-rows-left-to-right Use slidesPerRow instead of slidesPerColumn. As well as rows.

Comment: Weird, I couldnt find `slidesPerRow` in the documentation. However this doesnt work for me. If I do `slidesPerRow: 2` instead of `slidesPerColumn: 2` it displays in one line, grouped.

Comment: It seems like this option doesnt exist in swiper.

Comment: slidesPerView: 8,
      slidesPerColumnFill: 'column',
    slidesPerColumn: 2,

Comment: Same requirement here. Added an Issue to github proj https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed here: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/commit/88703faa525e49e468d38ca57d7345bdbee256ec and I can confirm it does work for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same Issue.
I just ordered my elements and fill the blank spaces with placeholder-elements.

I use this code here (but keep in mind, i always want 3 rows):

```
function orderMultiSlideRows($slides, placeholder, SlidesPerView) {
    let slidesLength = $slides.length,
        numberLastSlides = slidesLength % (SlidesPerView * 3),
        slideGroups = Math.ceil(slidesLength / (SlidesPerView * 3)),
        numberSlidesSum = slideGroups * (SlidesPerView * 3),
        numberSlidesPerRow = numberSlidesSum / 3,
        numberFilledSlidesPerRow = numberSlidesPerRow - SlidesPerView,
        currentRealSliderIndex = 0,
        htmlList = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < numberSlidesSum; i++) {
        if(i % numberSlidesPerRow >= numberFilledSlidesPerRow) {
            if(numberLastSlides > 0) {
                htmlList += $slides.get(currentRealSliderIndex).outerHTML;
                currentRealSliderIndex++;
                numberLastSlides--;
            } else {
                htmlList += placeholder;
            }
        } else {
            if(currentRealSliderIndex < slidesLength) {
                htmlList += $slides.get(currentRealSliderIndex).outerHTML;
                currentRealSliderIndex++;
            } else {
                // this should never happen
                htmlList += placeholder;
            }
        }
    }
    return $(htmlList);
}
```

hope this helps.
For cleaning you just remove all Placeholder-Elements (with a class or something)